# Mission accomplished?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

> 32811132

> 74131968

> 592162

> 289216

If you can say «mission accomplished», then you are a true ......

Hint:

> 32 8 111 32

Comment: I dare say "Mission accomplished!" Yes, I am a true cheater

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can say «mission accomplished», then you are a true

> Genius

> If you read the numbers as atomic numbers of the Periodic Table, you get:

> 32 8 111 32 = Ge O Rg Ge -> George (redundant "g")

> 74 13 19 68 = W Al K Er -> Walker

> 5 92 16 2 -> B U S He -> Bush (redundant "e")

> 28 92 16 -> Ni U S

> With the redundant letters from above with the letters from the fourth number, the word "genius" is formed, which answers the puzzle

Comment: So close, but look at the other reduntant characters as well...?

Comment: I can see a way to use them, but resulting in the same final answer. Gotta give more thought to it

Comment: If you update/edit your answer with the six reduntant letters, to form the sentence, then you are a true ...... and I will give you the bounty

Comment: Oh, I see. Updated my answer

Comment: Congratulation!

Comment: Thanks! That was a nice puzzle